# Is it not possible to get the class added with IServiceCollection::AddHostedService()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I created the default ASP.NET Core Web Application MVC project. Then, I added this.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddHostedService<MyService>(); //<-- What I added.
    }
```

`MyService` is a dummy class that implements `IHostedService`

```
public class MyService : IHostedService
{
    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Hello world");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Goodbye world");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Now, in the `HomeController`, I tried the following two things to get the instance of `MyService`, but both caused not-found or null exceptions.

```
    public IActionResult Index([FromServices] MyService ms)
    {

    public IActionResult Index([FromServices] IServiceProvider sp)
    {
        var ms = sp.GetService(typeof(MyService));
```

Is it not possible to get it? The modifications above are all I did to the default scaffolding, but if you need to browse the full source code, I uploaded it to [this Git repository](https://try.gitea.io/stackoverggarfsdfj324/question1/src/branch/master/WebApplication5).

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to inject your IHostedService in your controller? Seems *really* weird to me.

Anyhow, AddHostedService registers the implementation as Transient as can be seen here...

```
public static IServiceCollection AddHostedService<THostedService>(this IServiceCollection services)
        where THostedService : class, IHostedService
        => services.AddTransient<IHostedService, THostedService>();
}
```

...so the following should "work"

```
services.AddTransient<MyService>();
services.AddTransient<IHostedService>(x => return x.GetRequiredService<MyService>());
```

The only problem with this is that you will get a new fresh instance of your service everytime you inject/resolve it, and I don't think that's what you want.

So, **why** do you want to do this, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: First, thanks for letting me know why it is not working. The reason is that I want to create a background task that runs all the time and control (pause, resume, pass parameters) it using the web browser. Microsoft's [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio) says "Background tasks can be implemented as hosted services. A hosted service is a class with background task logic that implements the IHostedService interface." and their example `TimedHostedService` is implemented/registered like that.